# Handling HTML and Javascript encoded data using ESAPI in javascript

Tags: xss, esapi

If one performs HTML and Javascript encoding on the html content to prevent XSS (using 
`ESAPI,Encoder.encodeForJS(Encoder.encodeForHTML(untrustedData))`) 
    before sending the response to the client.
How to handle this HTML and Javascript encoded data in javascript?

Do I have to canonicalise the data before using the server output in element.innerHTML.

e.g,

```
var data = $ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize(serverOP); 

element.innerHTML=data;
```

But canonicalising data with mixed or multiple encoding will throw exception (Intrusion exception).

Comment: What's the javascript function going to do to the data its receiving as an argument?  A question like this has to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the server is first neutralizing HTML, and then neutralizing THAT data to be passed to a javascript function.

Is the javascript function you're targeting supposed to process HTML?

If you encode for HTML and then encode for javascript, you then need to call `ESAPI.encoder().decodeForJavascript(payload)` followed by `ESAPI.encoder().decodeForHtml(payload)`

Canonicalization is meant to be used to process data coming in from an *untrusted* source, and isn't a one-stop decoding function.

Further, if you know that your javascript function is the only entry point for this data, you shouldn't have to escape for html, just escape for javascript... I say this because "innerHTML" indicates that you intend for the browser to render what you're sending in, so you're doing extra work here by adding an unnecessary decoding step.

---

I wanted to add: If the server is passing escaped data intended to be passed to javascript, you won't want to decode it before using it.

Comment: I don't always get downvotes, but when I do, I'd like to know why?